# Error processing resource: An invalid character was found in text content

Tags: html, asp.net, pdf, webforms

I am getting the below error when trying to view a web page, can someone please let me know the cause and solution to resolve this error:

> ---
>
> The XML page cannot be displayed
>
> Cannot view XML input using style sheet.
>   Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try
>   again later.
>
> ---
>
> An invalid character was found in text content. Error processing
>   resource 'http://xxxxxxxxxxx/Auth/Ncoa/pdfviewer.asp...
>
> %

Code behind:

```
public class Ncoa_PdfViewer : Page
{
    protected HtmlForm _pdfViewer;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            ExpressBill.XNet.UI.Services.Ncoa ncoa = new ExpressBill.XNet.UI.Services.Ncoa("NcoaServiceUri");
            ((WebClientProtocol)ncoa).Timeout = -1;
            int clientId = int.Parse(this.Request.QueryString["clientid"]);
            byte[] pdfPackage;
            if (clientId == 0)
            {
                NcoaOwner owner = NcoaOwner.GetOwnerForPdfDisplay(this.Session);
                NcoaAgent[] agents = NcoaAgent.GetAgentsForPdfDisplay(this.Session);
                if (owner == null)
                    owner = new NcoaOwner();
                if (agents == null)
                    agents = new NcoaAgent[0];
                pdfPackage = ncoa.GetPDFPackage(owner, agents);
            }
            else
                pdfPackage = ncoa.GetPDFPackage(clientId);
            this.Response.Clear();
            this.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            this.Response.AddHeader("content-length", Convert.ToString(pdfPackage.Length));

            this.Response.BinaryWrite(pdfPackage);
            this.Response.Flush();
            this.Response.End();
        }
}
```

Design markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="ExpressBill.XNet.UI.Ncoa.Ncoa_PdfViewer" Codebehind="PdfViewer.aspx.cs" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<title>Pdf Viewer</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="_pdfViewer" runat="server">
<div>

</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is html can't read c# or whatever that is. If you want to make a website you can use `css, js, html, svg, or php`, but not c#. If html can read c# the computer will be very easy to hack. `html, js, css, svg, php` are different programming languages and they are very easy to learn. If you want more detail you can search w3school or watch youtube to get started.